# Is using GetLastInsertId safe for Web Application?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is this code safe in web application!

```
public Insert(Student s)
{
    con.Save<Student>(s);
    s.Id=con.GetLastInsertId();
}
```

I've investigated code of servicestack ormlite

```
public override long GetLastInsertId(IDbCommand dbCmd)
{
    dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    return dbCmd.GetLongScalar();
}
```

So is it big trap for beginners?

And how can we get filled Student instance like EF does? (Only Id must be filled)

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14319070/210085