# Why is service stack returning a Int64 instead of Int32?

Tags: servicestack

My model SecPermission has the column Id = int which is Int32. When I add a new record why is it returning the newly added ID as Int64?

Service method

```
public object Post(AddPermission request)
        {
            var perm = request.ConvertTo<SecPermission>();
            perm.AuditUserId = UserAuth.Id;
            LogInfo(typeof(SecPermission), request, LogAction.Insert);
            return Db.Insert(perm);
        }
```

Unit Test code

```
     using (var service = HostContext.ResolveService<SecurityService>(authenticatedRequest))
                    {
///**this line is returning an object with Int64 in it.
                        int id = (int) service.Post(new AddPermission { Name = name, Description = "TestDesc" });
                        service.Put(new UpdatePermission { Id = permission, Name = name,Description = "TestDesc" });
                        service.Delete(new DeletePermission { Id = Convert.ToInt32(id)});
                    }

     public class SecPermission : IAudit
            {
                [AutoIncrement]
                [PrimaryKey]
                public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(75)]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public PermissionType PermissionType { get; set; }

            public int AuditUserId { get; set; }
            public DateTime AuditDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never return a Value Type in a ServiceStack Service, it needs to be a reference Type, typically a Typed Response DTO but can also be a raw data type like `string` or `byte[]` but it should never be a Value Type like an integer which will fail to work in some ServiceStack features.

For this Service I'd either return the `SecPermission` object or a `AddPermissionResponse` object with the integer in the result value.

Please note that OrmLite `Insert()` API returns a `long` which is why you're seeing a long, however you need to either [call Save() or specify selectIdentity:true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14319070/85785) in order to fetch the newly inserted id of an `[AutoIncrement]` primary key, e.g:

```
var newId = db.Insert(perm, selectIdentity:true);
```

or

```
Db.Save(perm);
var newId = perm.Id; //auto populated with auto incremented primary key
```

Also you don't need both `[PrimaryKey]` and `[AutoIncrement]` in OrmLite as `[AutoIncrement]` specifies a Primary Key on its own as does using an [Id property convention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#single-primary-key).

Also if you're going to call the Service directly you may as well Type the Response to avoid casting, e.g:

```
public SecPermission Post(AddPermission request)
{
    //...
    Db.Save(perm);
    return perm;
}
```

Then you don't need to cast when calling it directly, e.g:

```
var id = service.Post(new AddPermission { ... }).Id;
```

There's no behavioral difference in ServiceStack for using `object` or a typed response like `SecPermission` although it's preferably to specify it on your Request DTO using the `IReturn<T>` interface marker, e.g:

```
public AddPermission : IReturn<SecPermission> { ... }
```

As it enables end-to-end Typed APIs when called from Service Clients, e.g:

```
SecPermission response = client.Post(new AddPermission { ... });
```